# Alguien sabe como resolver este error de laravel?

Tags: laravel

estoy tratando de hacer un filtro con un select pero al momento de darle al boton de filtrado me aparece este errory sinceramente no se como arreglar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del controlador

```
public function filtro(Request $request){
    $empleos = empleo::query();
    $staff_select = $request->staff_select;

    if(!empty($staff_select)){
        $empleos = $empleos->where('staff', $staff_select);
    }

     $empleos = $empleos->get();

     return view('empleos.index')->with(compact('empleos'));
}
```

y este es el codigo de la vista index

```
            <div class="media-form" style="background: rgb(235, 235, 235)">
              <form action="{{route('empleos.filtro') }}" method="GET" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 float-right" >
                <select name="staff_select">
                  <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
                  @foreach($empleos as $empleo)
                     <option value="{{$empleo->staff}}">{{$empleo->staff}}</option>
                  @endforeach
               </select>
               <br>
                  <button type="submit">Filtrar resultados</button>
              </form>
            </div>
```

y por si acaso estas son las rutas

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');
Route::get('/', [EmpleoController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');
Route::get('empleos/filtrado-de', [EmpleoController::class, 'filtro'])->name('empleos.filtro');
```

Gracias por su ayuda, disculpen es que no soy muy diestro en Laravel y trato de aprender

Comment: ¿Seguro que este es el código que genera problemas?

Comment: Si porque es el codigo que recien agregue

Comment: No es todo, pero esa parte es la que me genera conflicto, te voy a ser sincero, esa parte lo trate de adaptar a mi proyecto, pero a lo que me dices esta mal, que deberia hacer cambiarlo, quitarlo??

Comment: Ahi dice en el error algo referido a que estás tratando de usar un método llamado `fragment` sobre una colección, esa es pa parte que interesa

Comment: Pero que yo recuerde no he llamado un metodo llamado fragment